# Fastest method: for value in DictA, find value in DictB and retrieve other DictB value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, search

For each item in dictA, I want to search for it in dictB, if dictB has it then I want to pull some other values from dictB and add it to dictA.

An example that is working is here, however it is rather slow as I have 50,000+ items to search through and it will perform this similar function on multiple dicts.

Is there a fast method of performing this search?

```
dictA = [
    {'id': 12345},
    {'id': 67890},
    {'id': 11111},
    {'id': 22222}
]

dictB = [
    {'id': 63351, 'name': 'Bob'},
    {'id': 12345, 'name': 'Carl'},
    {'id': 59933, 'name': 'Amy'},
    {'id': 11111, 'name': 'Chris'}
]

for i in dictA:
    name = None
    for j in dictB:
        if i['id'] == j['id']:
            name = j['name']
    i['name'] = name
```

The dictA output after this would be:

```
dictA = [
    {'id': 12345, 'name': 'Carl'},
    {'id': 67890, 'name': None},
    {'id': 11111, 'name': 'Chris'},
    {'id': 22222, 'name': None}
]
```

Comment: `id` will be unique in both `dictA` and `dictB`? Btw what you showed is a `list of dict` not a `dict`.

Comment: Create an inverse dictionary of `dictB` but that would involve more memory

Comment: flattening your dicts to `A = {12345: None, 12346: None...}`, and `B = {12345: 'Carl', 67890: 'Chris'}` will give you the best performance for this operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The given is list of dict. You can create dict from that assuming `id` is uninque. Converting from `list of dict` to `dict` will work for your case.

```py
dictA = [
    {'id': 12345},
    {'id': 67890},
    {'id': 11111},
    {'id': 22222}
]

dictB = [
    {'id': 63351, 'name': 'Bob'},
    {'id': 12345, 'name': 'Carl'},
    {'id': 59933, 'name': 'Amy'},
    {'id': 11111, 'name': 'Chris'}
]


actual_dictB = dict()
for d in dictB:
    actual_dictB[d['id']] = d['name']

for i in dictA:
    i['name'] = actual_dictB.pop(i['id'], None) # now search have became O(1) constant. So best time complexity achived O(n) n=length of dictA

print(dictA)
```

- Follow up for additional question:

```py
actual_dictB = dict()
for d in dictB:
    id_ = d['id']
    d.pop('id')
    actual_dictB[id_] = d

    
tmp = dict([(k,None) for k in dictB[0].keys() if k!='id'])
           
for i in dictA:
    if i['id'] not in actual_dictB:
        i.update(tmp)
    else:
        i.update(actual_dictB[i['id']])
print(dictA)
```

Comment: `dictB = {d['id']: d['name'] for d in dictB}` more succinct; overwrites original `dictB`

Comment: @Poojan this seems to be working well and is much faster! I am a little confused on how to return multiple items from dictB if needed though? E.g. what if dictB also had `'birth_year': 2020` that I wanted to pull into dictA?

Comment: @Matty you need to have `dict` as value of `dictB`. See updated answer